# Transferring system logs to a remote port

Tags: rhel, syslog

I want to transfer all system logs to a remote machine's port.

**RHEL version :**

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11

**The performed actions:**

Adding below line to /etc/syslog.conf

```
*.* @10.100.7.2:6680
```

**Then restart syslog daemon:**

```
service syslog stop
service syslog start
```

But I cannot see the logs in the remote machine. IP is pingable. There is no rsyslog installed in the os environment. Do you think any additional modification needed?

Answer (score 1):

you must install rsyslog on remote host to handle incomming syslog packet.

I use tho following setting in /etc/rsyslog.d/remote.conf

```
$UDPServerRun 514         # start a UDP syslog server at standard port 514
module(load="imudp") # needs to be done just once
input(type="imudp" port="514")

$template RemoteHost,"/var/log/remote/%HOSTNAME%/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%-%$DAY%.log"

*.* ?RemoteHost
```

In your case, you must replace 514 by 6680.

On sending hosts (hosts that I want to capture rsyslog), I use (/etc/rsyslog.d/distant.conf)

```
*.* action(type="omfwd" target="8.8.8.8" port="514" protocol="udp" action.resumeRetryCount="10" )
```

with 8.8.8.8 being IP of host above.